# Problem in installing glibc-devel packager

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 system.

I am installing `ltib` in my system. It gives following error.

```
defined(@array) is deprecated at /home/saurabhkagarwal/ONGF_PCD/MPC8308/ltib-mpc8308erdb-20100413/bin/Ltibutils.pm line 360.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)

ltib cannot be run because one or more of the host packages needed to run it
are either missing or out of date or not in ltib's standard path.  Please
install/upgrade these packages on your host.  If you have your own utilities
in non-standard paths, please add an entry into the .ltibrc file for example:

%path_std 

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/my/own/exes

Package                Minimum ver   Installed info
-------                -----------   ---------------
glibc-devel            0             not installed

Died at ./ltib line 1397.
traceback:
 main::host_checks:1397
  main:542


Started: Mon Mar 30 03:29:27 2015
Ended:   Mon Mar 30 03:29:28 2015
Elapsed: 1 seconds


Build Failed

Exiting on error or interrupt
```

Following this, I did try to install glibc-devel package but my system can not locate the package.

```
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel
```

I am getting this error.

```
E: Unable to locate package glibc-devel
```

So after searching on Internet, I have tried following solutions

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

But still I am getting the same Error.

Comment: How do you install `tlib`

Comment: I have a freescale MPC8308 Embedded board. So I downloaded Board support Package from freescale website. This BSP has a script to install ltib. Also, I applied following patches to given BSP. https://github.com/lerwys/Installation_instructions/tree/master/patches/ltib/fixes

Comment: `glibc-devel` sounds like a RedHat (RPM) package name. You'll need to back up and list the exact steps you've done so far during the install.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch available for installing tlib in ubuntu. 
https://github.com/lerwys/Installation_instructions/tree/master/patches/ltib/

It solves the above error.

After this I came across the problem of rpmdb. So Patch for this is available at 
https://github.com/lerwys/Installation_instructions/tree/master/patches/ltib/fixes

IMPORTANT NOTE:
At first, I applied patches from second link and after that i applied patch from first link.
It didn't work.

After this I applied Patch from first link and then rpmdb patch from second link. It works.

After this I got this error

```
failed to install pme_tools package.
```

A patch is available for this in second link.

Things might change from system to system. So, apply only those patches which are necessary otherwise you will get some undefined behaviour.